# Scala Parser Combinator define issues

Tags: scala, parsing

I've just started using Scala a few days ago and wanted to write my first parser.

the problematic code is as follows:

```
  val withoutZero: Parser[List[String]] = ("1" | "2" | "3" | "4").+
  val withZero: Parser[String] = "0" | withoutZero
```

the number string I'd like to parse can have multiple zeros and other numbers but I want to define two functions for it.

the combined withZero has to stay String (not List[String] or whatever else). at the moment I'm only parsing one zero because ("0").+ didn't work out.

my question:
how am I able to adjust the withZero Parser to multiple zeros AND
combining it with the withoutZero Parser still staying a Parser[String]

Comment: Can you give some examples of grammatical strings? It's not entirely clear to me from your description.

Comment: it should parse: 0+ | (1|2|3|4)+

Comment: The stuff on either side of the `|` has to be the same type, so I still don't understand—it guess I'd still like to see actual strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for `0+ | (1|2|3|4)+`:

```
val withZero: Parser[String] = (literal("0").+ | withoutZero) ^^ (_.mkString)
```

It joins the list of `String`s from some parser into a single `String`

Comment: thanks only problem:
      value mkString is not a member of java.io.Serializable

Comment: @TwelveDollar It's a member of `scala.collection.TraversableOnce` and via inheritance member of `List` and all other collections. Do you have anything else within parenthese? Some of the Parsers in the parentheses is not a Parser[List[String]], it seems. It works as seen here: http://goo.gl/VswKRb

Comment: okay thanks, can't see any mistake copied your tutorialspoint code resulting in the same error. I'll fix that myself. code works as intended therefore answer accepted. (y)!